# How to create custom UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to create my custom `UISegmentedControl` like in the image below. There should be a gap between the buttons like in the screenshot. I have searched but did not get a complete solution.

Here is screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I tried this:

````
let items = ["Dialy", "Weekly", "Monthly"]    
lazy var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl = {  
    let control = UISegmentedControl(items: items)      
    control.selectedSegmentIndex = 0     
    control.layer.cornerRadius = 9      
    control.layer.borderWidth = 1      
    control.layer.masksToBounds = true      
    control.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor  
    control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentControl(sender:)), for:.touchUpInside)    
    return control    
}()
```
````

Comment: UISegmentedControl doesn't support that level of customization. You would need to create your own custom UIControl.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your first step should always be ***searching***. Head over to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift custom UISegmentedControl` ... you will probably find code already done for this. If not, you will at least find code you can customize to meet your needs.